# For validating session attribute, which is better in spring - Interceptor or Spring AOP?

Tags: spring, interceptor, spring-aop

In my application, after a user is logged in, every time he sends a request (get/post), before calling the method in controller, i want to verify the session attribute set in the request (i set a session attribute during his login). I see that **this can be implemented through spring interceptors (OR) spring AOP**. which one should i use?. I have a feeling interceptors are outdated. **Or is there a way in spring security which does this** for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring security way seems the best way to me with access to specific roles also can be assigned. very good example given in http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

Answer (score 0):

So you want this intercept to happen only for all the controller methods ..? Does the controller have Base URL that its getting invoked for (post/get/delete)...? Is it more like you want to intercept the http request for a particualt URL ..? like this one

```
<intercept-url pattern="/styles/**" filters=" .." />
```

If your use case is boiled down to a particular URL pattern then you can write a custom filter extending `GenericFilterBean` and you can plug it to the filters attribute.So this will get called for every request matching url pattern and in  your custom filter you can do whatever you wanted to do.

Comment: I want to eclude some urls for my interceptors which not available in spring versions prior to  3.2.5 and i use spring 3.0.5. so i dont prefer this way since i will have to list out all the url patterns.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try implementing a simple Filter? You can extend already existing [Spring filter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html), or create your own by implementing [javax.servlet.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)